# How to retrieve data to build a histogram in dynamoDB using scan in just one query

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

Im trying to build a histogram of a certain attribute in my dynamodb.
I can get all the values by running multiple `scan count` queries and changing the ranges each time

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name test --select "COUNT"  \
--filter-expression "(score between :s and :s1)"  \
--expression-attribute-values '{ ":s": { "N": "0" }, ":s1": { "N": "10" } }'
```

My question is: can i do it all in **one** scan, getting counts for values 0-9, 10-19, ... 90-100 ?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is **no** - you can't do it with a single scan.

To expand on that, there are two blockers to achieving what you want:

1)  A scan returns up to a maximum of 1MB of data per call (see the [per-api limits section in the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html#limits-api)) so in a general sense, you will need a sequence of Scan calls to read all data from a table

2) DynamoDB does not support aggregation queries which is what you're really asking for. What this means is that you can't ask it to group data into buckets for you and you can't ask it to give you counts, or sums of items

So, what you must do is run the scans without any filter and then implement the grouping and aggregation in your application. This is essentially a map/reduce operation: map the items based on the score into buckets and reduce using a count to generate the histograms.

Answer (score 1):

As Mike pointed out DynamoDB does not support aggregation queries.
However there was a valuable tip: MapReduce

1. Create an Amazon cluster, ssh into it
2. Map the dynamoDB table to a hive table
3. increase the read capacity on your dynamodb table (my table has 300M items, so i upped the read capacity to 4000)
4. Run the mapReduce query using hive:
   `hive> select score, count(score)  from  (select score from hive_my_table limit 300000000) as t1 GROUP by score;`
   My query took 2054 sec to run.
   I got a score and the number of instances of it (so a full histogram)

Tip: do not be afraid to increase your read capacity, you will save on the cluster runtime. With read capacity of 100 I calculated the query would take over a day to complete.

Comment: Awesome! Yes, HIVE with a DynamoDB connector works pretty well and it's not that difficult to set up. However, I would caution against increasing the provisioned read capacity by too much because it will cause your table to split and you may pay the price of the splits later down the road. Finding a middle of the road solution that doesn't take too long to execute makes the most sense. Having an analytics query run for a couple of hours is not that terrible if you don't need to run it too often.